# Python read append more that one line to a list from a text file

Tags: python

I have a text file of a network device configuration and I have my scrip loops through the lines of the file and here is what I'm looking for:

I would like to have my script append to a list if it finds a specific word in the line. so far I'm only able to append one single line to my list...here is an example:

```
my_file = open('configs.txt', 'r')
license = []
for line in my_file:    
    if line.startswith ("show license verbose"):
        license.append(line)    
print license
```

so far it only gets me that one single line with "show license verbose". and I want it to get me say 5 more line after that phrase is found.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to fetch succeeding lines from the file object:

```
from itertools import islice

my_file = open('configs.txt', 'r')
license = []
for line in my_file:    
    if line.startswith("show license verbose"):
        license.append(line)
        license.extend(islice(my_file, 5))
print license
```

Comment: Thanks @Moses Koledoye. how can I have it read more lines and append them and stop when it sees "show version" meaning I want to append everything between "show license verbose" and "show version"

Comment: @FrankBud I think it will be better if you asked that in another question since we already provided an answer to this one.

Comment: Well you answered with the itertools islice and I was reading that I can pass it a start and stop parameter and thought to follow up to your original question. Am I on the right track so I can ask a new clear question around the itertools islice??

Comment: Probably. But note that since we don't where the line with the stop condition will be found, it would be tricky using `islice` since the stop condition is unknown a priori whereas `islice` would require that you pass `stop` before a *slice* can be done

Comment: Thank you @Moses Koledoye I will ask the question after i I play with islice.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_file = open('configs.txt', 'r')
license = []

for line in my_file:
    if line.startswith ("show license verbose"):
        license.append(line)
        for (i, line) in zip( range(1, 6), my_file ):
            license.append( line )

print( license )
```

It's python3 code for python 2 you probably will want to remove brackets in last  print and use `xrange` instead of `range`

Comment: Thank you a lot @Arnial . that is exactly what I'm looking for. just have to lookup what the zip() does :)

Comment: Glad to read it. I thing you should select @Moses Koledoye answer as best. First - code looks cleaner (less identation), seond - itertools is part of standart python library written in C, its, probably, will be faster

Answer (score 1):

open returns a generator therefore you might be able to use next method:

```
# you don't need this input as you already has generator
source = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
# turn it to generator
g = (i for i in source)
# create empty list
lines = []
# put what you want inside
for item in g:
    if item=='c': # this can be replaced with .startswith()
        lines.append(item)
        for i in range(4):
            lines.append(next(g))

In : lines
Out: ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```